# How to apply lintChecks to all dependent modules?

Tags: android, lint

I created a custom Lint check and want the check applied to all dependent modules in my Android project. The custom Lint check lives in the `checks` module, and I can successfully run it in other modules by adding `lintChecks project(":checks")` to their respective `build.gradle` files. What I'd like to do is add something similar to `api <dependency>`, so all dependent modules also run the check. There is a core module already serving the purpose for other functionalities. Is there an API or configuration to prevent `lintChecks` redundancy? Such that all I'd have to do is add `lintChecks project(":checks")` to the core module.

Comment: Not sure if I'm getting this right, but if you want to add/apply something to all projects you can do so in the `allProjects` block in the root build.gradle

Comment: @JenV Yep, that's what I want to do. I tried adding `lintChecks` to a `dependencies` block inside `allprojects`, but received an error. `A problem occurred evaluating root project 'mobile-android'.
> Could not find method lintChecks() for arguments [project ':checks'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.` Any idea what's going wrong? I tried various `apply` statements used in other `build.gradle` files.

Comment: did you find a solution to this @clever_trevor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not create an `IssueRegistry` file in the correct directory, resulting in Gradle not showing the task. Found out `lintChecks` in `build.gradle` files was never necessary.

Comment: could you please explain further what was wrong with your impl and got you misled at the first place?